# Rails 3 sorting through parent association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I have a fairly straightforward question in Rails 3 to which I can't seem to find the answer:

Let's say I have 2 models: Customer, Project.

A Customer has_many projects
Project belongs_to customer

Now I want to sort a list of projects by "customer name" using Active Record (doing it with a Ruby array is easy enough, but I imagine this will get problematic once the number of project records grows).

How do I go about doing this with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Project.joins(:customer).order('customers.name')
```

Comment: I did try that one but that nets me:  

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'customer.name' in 'order clause': SELECT     `projects`.* FROM       `projects`  INNER JOIN `customers` ON `customers`.`id` = `projects`.`customer_id` ORDER BY  customer.name

Comment: Use 'customers.name', not 'customer.name' (fixed in answer)

Comment: @valodzka, I know this is what this community is about but thank you for that clarification. I was using the singular syntax because I had a has_one relationship not realizing it still needed to be plural (customers.name vs customer.name) as you stated in the above comment and answer. This helped me a ton even still two years after you answered it.