# problem using default_scope on a model table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hey. In my controller/index action I use the following query:

```
@course_enrollments = current_user.course_enrollments
```

This is what my table looks like. It is referencing  a course table. The course table has a colum 'title'.

```
create_table "course_enrollments", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id",    :null => false
  t.integer  "course_id",  :null => false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I want to be able to order my course_enrollments by course in my index view. Furthermore Id like to do a default_scope in my model, like this:

```
  default_scope :order => 'title asc'
```

any suggestions? Thx for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort through a parent model, follow the instructions at [Rails 3 sorting through parent association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891413/rails-3-sorting-through-parent-association), namely:

```
CourseEnrollments.joins(:course).order('courses.title')
```

For a default scope, you should be able to use:

```
default_scope joins(:course).order('courses.title')
```